# Добавление iframe в html

Tags: python, html, css, django, iframe

У меня есть шаблон Anime.html с частью кода

```html
<div class="player__wrapper">
  <div class="player__item"></div>
    {{ anime.iframe_code }}
</div>
```

models.py

```py
class Anime(models.Model):
    """Страница аниме"""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Название аниме")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="URL")
    poster = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    iframe_code = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        """Возвращает строковое представление модели"""
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('anime', kwargs={'anime_slug':self.slug})
```

нужно чтобы iframe_code в шаблоне отображлся не как текст, а как часть кода html, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Я понял как можно реализовать это, нужно было в anime.html всего лишь добавить сам iframe с src из него добавлять в базу данных. То есть вставлять только ссылку на видео

**Старый код**

```
<div class="player__wrapper">
  <div class="player__item"></div>
  {{ anime.iframe_code }}
</div>
```

**Новый**

```
<div class="player__wrapper">
    <div class="player__item"></div>
    <iframe class="kodik-player" src="{{ anime.iframe_code }}" AllowFullScreen allow="autoplay *; fullscreen *"></iframe>
</div>
```